# How to implement Null Object pattern with Date?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I would like to use the [Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) for java.util.Date. I have a function that returns some Date, but it can also be that no meaningful Date can be returned.

I would like to avoid returning `null` for the usual reasons why one would like to avoid nulls (nullpointer issues).

At the moment I am returning `new Date(0)` to indicate an "null date" and checking for `returnedDate.equals(new Date(0))` downstream where I need to know whether I have a real date or not, but I'm not convinced that this is the best way.

Comment: It is better to return null then check for null before using.  ex.  if(date != null)

Comment: Why you cannot return null and just check the return value of the called method (with an if statement for instance)?

Comment: Using null in the right way is not a bad thing. In fact it can help you find potential logical errors in your code.

Comment: @karvoynistas I am saving the returned date in another data structure for later calculations and retrieval. It is meaningful information to me whether the date is "invalid". Thus I would need to check for null not only immediately after returning from the one function, but in many other places in the code. The danger to forget it somewhere is thus quite real.

Comment: You don't have to check the generated Date before you use it in the other places of your code? You are willing on make computations based on wrong Date(0) objects? Then you will have to deal with logical errors and it will be more difficult than put an if statement wherever you have to

Comment: @karvoynistas Now that I think about it, you might be right. I might be trading protection against nullpointers with introducing logical errors here.

Comment: Do your null values have special purposes? E.g. since ever out for ever?

Comment: @keuleJ yes it's something like that: "too far in future", or "never happened". I considered using a static final variable, but since Date is not immutable that would also be unsafe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `Optional` Class

Try using the [`Optional`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) class added to Java 8. [This article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html) demonstrates.

## Guava Library

The [Google Guava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava) library has a similar type. [This article](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained) explains.

Comment: Thanks, I think indeed Optional would be ideal in this case! Unfortunately I'm stuck with lower Java versions for the moment and I don't know if adding Guava dependency is worth it here. But if I didn't have these constraints, then this would be indeed the right way for me.

Comment: @jhyot Yes, it sounds like Optional is exactly what you need given your comments. Mishandling nulls will halt your entire app with a NullPointerException. That justifies adding Guava as a dependency. Guava is a simple addition, with no further dependencies. And Guava has many other handy features. So I recommend you consider that route.

Answer (score 0):

I'm slightly confused at what you're asking.

If you are declaring a `new Date()` object of any kind, then the object will never be null. I think what you are trying to do is avoid setting a Date to be null and instead creating an arbitrary date, `new Date(0)` to use later in your program.

I would advise against this practice and I don't think it's the best way.

My recommendation is to keep the object null and make some sort of check:

```
Date date;
if(date != null)
{
    // code goes here
}
```

In essence, you – I think – are already doing this check (checking for the arbitrary date object).

As a reminder, here are the following date parameters as defined in the Java `Date` class:

```
// Creates today's date/time
Date()

// Creates a date
Date(long)
Date(int, int, int)
Date(int, int, int, int, int)
Date(int, int, int, int, int, int)
Date(String)
```

Once you have enough information to create the `Date` object downstream in your program is when I would advise creating it.

Feel free to provide more information / more code to aid in this discussion.

Comment: I wanted to apply the [Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern), the point of which is indeed that a returned object will never be null, but have a "safe" behaviour in any case. But after reading the answer and the comments, I think that maybe the Null Object pattern is not applicable here after all... see also my comments below the question. I will think about this a bit more. Thanks so far!

Comment: I agree. I'm not sure if the `Null Object Pattern` is appropriate here, but it's definitely a consideration you should continue to think about.